# what can cause a timeout in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-4

I have other queries working with the same connectionstring; the server is returning data on those calls.

some settings:
Connection.ConnectionTimeout = 3600 (in debugger)
DB timeout is set to 0

```
<add
   name="StuffEntities"
   connectionString="metadata=res://*/DataModel.Stuff.csdl|res://*/DataModel.Stuff.ssdl|res://*/DataModel.Stuff.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=10.0.1.Stuff;initial catalog=Stuff;persist security info=True;user id=Stuff;password=Stuff;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework;Connect Timeout=3600&quot;"
   providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

outer Exception

> {"An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the
>   inner exception for details."}

Inner Exception

> {"Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of
>   the operation or the server is not responding."} error code :
>   -2146232060

looks like it happens in 30 seconds.

I have no clue what is overriding my settings.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the generated sql to help find the problem? There are a few options available, SQL Profiler, MiniProfiler, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
context.CommandTimeout = 3600;
```

forgot to change that one.

silly me.

Comment: This isn't a fix. This is like making your lawn greener by covering it with a green tarp. Why not address the problem that your query takes longer than 30 seconds in the first place?

Comment: pulling too many images in one go; most of the time it is fine, but over wifi it gets sad.